# Number of matrices with 'small' entries in integer matrix groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $G \leq {\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$
be finitely generated. Given a bound $b \in \mathbb{N}$, let $e_b$ be
the number of elements of $G$ all of whose matrix entries have absolute
value $\leq b$.

**Question:** Does $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \ln{e_b}/\ln{b}$ always
exist? And if yes, which values can this limit take, depending on $G$?

Comment: For $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ itself, I think the limit is 2 (surprisingly not 3). To get the better estimate, first use that the number of coprimes pairs $\le m$ is $\simeq m^2$ (see https://oeis.org/A018805; I don't care with constants). This means (roughly: somewhat in average) that the number of coprime pairs $(a,b)$ with $m\ge a\ge b\ge 0$ when $a$ is fixed is $\simeq a$. Then the number of Bezout solutions $au+bv=1$ less than $m$ is $\simeq m/a$. So for $a$ fixed the number of solutions is $\simeq m$. Summing over $a$, it implies that the number of solutions is $\simeq m^2$.

Comment: (Sorry I changed $b$ to $m$ in my comment... making $n$ a constant and $b$ a variable gives me headaches.)

Comment: Apart from this, a few simple observations: for a subgroup of exponential growth the liminf is $>0$. For a group of polynomial growth the liminf is $>0$ iff it contains a unipotent element (in which case the liminf is $\ge 1/(d-1)$, where $d$ is the dimension ($n$ in the question)). The remains cases have limsup 0, these are precisely those (virtually abelian) subgroups for which the Zariski closure is virtually a torus. In dimension $d$, the case of a cyclic subgroup generated by a unipotent matrix with maximal Jordan block realizes the limit $1/(d-1)$.

Comment: As n grows, the number of Hadamard matrices of order n grows quickly.  I don't understand the situation of your question well, but my intuition suggests that using Hadamard matrices as generators (or lots of square roots of diagonal matrices) will show there is no limit.  Gerhard "So Many Ways To Multiply" Paseman, 2017.12.10.

Comment: Using quantitatively the method of the QI ping-pong lemma (http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/tq.pdf, Lemma 2.3, or any similar statement), I guess one can produce, in $SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$, free subgroups for which the limsup is arbitrary small. Namely, we need to find, for every $M$, elements $a,b\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, such that for every $k$ and every $w$ in the $k$-sphere of the free group $F_2$, we have $\|w(a,b)\|\ge M^k$. If so, we the limsup $\le\ln(3)\ln(M)$.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman What do you mean by "grows quickly"... "there is no limit"? The limsup is clearly $\le d^2$ (and easily $\le d^2-1$), where $d$ is the dimension. So there's a limsup and a liminf, and as I said, if the liminf vanishes so does the limsup. So all what might happen is that $0<\liminf<\limsup\le d^2-1$, but this would be a matter of irregular growth, not of fast growth.

Comment: @YCor: Shouldn't it be limsup $\leq \frac{\ln{(3)}}{\ln{(M)}}$ at the end of your second-last comment?

Comment: @StefanKohl yes, sorry it's a misprint (I wanted to make the limsup small). Anyway, I haven't checked details for this "Schottky" example.